# How can we print on CDs with printer

Tags: printing, compact-disc

I have got Blank CDs with white surface.

Is Are there any special printers which can print on them.
i want to print them in bulk. mays its only Black and white

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any special printers which
>   can print on them.

Yes, there are ... for example the **[MantraJet 1050 CD/DVD auto-printer](http://www.yurex.com/autoprinters.html)**

[image]

- Standard HP cartridges
- True photo print quality
- 50 or 100 disc capacity
- Use any graphics application. There is no need for any special duplication software.Just enter how many copies you need in the print dialog box of any label design software and come back when all discs are printed
- Ultra-high speed loading mechanism
- Excellent service-ability
- Powerful fan to minimize the ink contamination
- Smallest footprint in the industry - perfect for live event recording

Or the **[DYMO DiscPainter](http://global.dymo.com/enUS/DiscPainter/default.html)**

[image]

TEAC and Casio offer black&white thermal transfer disk printers which are cheaper ($50-100).

[image]

[image]

Comment: First one is very costly around 3000$ in Australia. while other ones are very slow. Currently i am using Avery mini address labels 33 in 1page and using them. I think that is ok for now. i can't spend more than 300$

Answer (score 1):

Please do check what type of dics you have. A thermal transfer printer won't print on an disc prepared for inkjet printing, and an inkjet printer won't print on a disc for thermal printing.

Answer (score 0):

We do this with an [Epson](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/CDLanding.jsp) inkjet. Just as another option. But the previously posted ones would do better for bulk.